# What's this icon?

Tags: notification-icons

What is that balloon icon? I think it must be a downloaded app but I can't figure which.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you use anything AMD related on this device? Radeon uses an icon similar to that now.

Comment: Where did you found this icon?

Answer (score 2):

Moments a picture share app from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Android version you might be able to long press a notification (if there is any) to find out the app it comes from.
Or maybe a reverse image search with google will do.